# How to assign a result of an arrow function (=>) to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

I am trying to have an arrow function **result** assigned to a variable, as follows:

```
function mutation(arr) {

  let allThere = true 

  while (allThere) {
    for (let c of arr[1]) {

      //the function in question below this line
      allThere = (c) => { 
        if (!arr[0].includes(c)) {
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return allThere;
```

So what I am hoping to happen is to have a boolean **value** returned from the arrow function and stored in `allThere`, but what actually happens is that the entire **function** is stored in that variable and not the **result** of the function. I might be missing something basic here.

(As a side question, I am wondering if there is a way to make the arrow function return a value directly to the external function `mutations(arr)`).

Comment: Why have the function at all? It doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: In this simplified example, you might be right. I am still interested to know in principle how to be able to assign a result of an anonymous function to a variable and not the function itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what I am hoping to happen is to have a boolean value returned from the arrow function and stored in `allThere`

To do that, you have to *call* the function. Defining and calling a function at the same time is called an IIFE ("inline-invoked" [or "immediately-invoked"] "function expression"):

```
    allThere = ((c) => { 
//             ^
      if (!arr[0].includes(c)) {
        return false
      }
    })()
//   ^^^
```

but note you need to handle both cases (true and false):

```
allThere = ((c) => { 
  return !arr[0].includes(c);
})()
```

...which can be written as a concise arrow function:

```
allThere = ((c) => !arr[0].includes(c))();
```

...but of course, doesn't need to be a function at all:

```
allThere = !arr[0].includes(c);
```

> (As a side question, I am wondering if there is a way to make the arrow function return a value directly to the external function mutations(arr)).

Yes, because the function *closes over* the variables in the context where it appears, so you *could* do:

```
((c) => { 
  if (!arr[0].includes(c)) {
    allThere = false
  }
})()
```

...but again, there's no reason for a function there.

Comment: That quite solved the problem. Thank you (and for the other tips as well).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use IIFE (immediate Invoked Function Expression) in that case:

```js
function mutation(arr) {

  let allThere = true 

  while (allThere) {
    for (let c of arr[1]) {

      //the function in question below this line
      allThere = ((c) => { 
        if (!arr[0].includes(c)) {
          return false
        }
      })();//Immediately invoke the expression here to get the return value
    }
  }

  return allThere;
}
console.log(mutation([['1'], ['2']]));
```

For the side question you can return after you invoked the IIFE:

```js
function mutation(arr) {

  let allThere = true 

  while (allThere) {
    for (let c of arr[1]) {

      //the function in question below this line
     return ((c) => { 
        if (!arr[0].includes(c)) {
          return false
        }
      })();//Immediately invoke the expression here to get the return value
    }
  }    
}
 console.log(mutation([['1'], ['2']]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just assigning to a function not executing the function. Which looks even useless in this way. Use `every`:

`console.log(arr[1].every(c => arr[0].includes(c)));`

Comment: The way to learning is paved with many useless anonymous functions :) Thanks for the `arr.every` tip.

Comment: Investigating your suggestion further, it seems like it is better to use `some()` in this case and not `every()`.